# how to Add Limit of Video Recording in Android HTC WildFire S?

Tags: android, android-camera

Using below Code I set Limit of Video Recording,But it can't works?

`My Device version is 2.3.3.(Higher than API-8)` and i would like to add `limit 60 seconds.`

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,60);

//OR  cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit",60);  

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,TAKE_VIDEO);
```

is there **Any Solution using Implicit intent** ? or I have to code using Camera and SurfaceView For Limit.

From [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT)

Comment: Downvoter care to say why downvoted ?

Comment: Hi Samir, did you find any solution to this problem ? Because I am facing the same problem. If you have solution please share. O/w I will also move to Camera and Surface View